# Run 2 versions of Java on OSX

Tags: java, macos

Is there an idiots guide to running 2 versions of Java on OSX? I need an older version to run a Webstart app that requires Java 6 to run, but other applications on my machine need the Java 7 update.

I'm not exactly a OSX under-the-hood guru, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It is possible to have 2 JDK's installed at once. Have you considered simply changing the environment variables when launching the applications? Maybe make a batch script that precedes the webstart app and specifies the JDK to use?

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: I'm not sure what webstart apps are, is it itself being invoked via a .bat file? If so, you can add a lines, SET JAVA_HOME=(JDK Loc), and, SET JRE_HOME=(JDK Loc). If you manually run the application, as in not through an IDE, you could make a .bat file that set's the variable then executes the app.

Comment: What webserver are you using? is it tomcat or glassfish or something else? Most likely, these servers should come with a environment setup script. In case of tomcat, it is set-env.sh. Inside that file, you could add the path to your required version of Java. There will be something similar for other web containers.

Comment: I don't have control over the server. I need to install both versions of Java (Java 6 and Java 7) and point the application that depends on Java 6 to it and fall back to Java 7 for everything else.